# Can we install multiple Domino servers in single Domain?

Tags: exchange-server, lotus-domino

Can we install 2 Domino server in a single domain?
Can we install a Domino and a MS Exchange server in a single domain?

Comment: What do you mean by domain? Internet domain, Notes domain, Windows domain ?

Comment: I mean Internet Domain

Comment: This question belongs to http://serverfault.com/ as it is administration and not development related. Look here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Yes you can. Just add the second domino to the MX-Record. Domino and Exchange in the same domain, maybe with smarthost settings ?

Answer (score 1):

lets answer this at the same detail level as the question: Yes you can...